# how do i use sed to replace an power expression in sv

Tags: sed

> I have used the below command to replace the "2**n"

> sed -i 's|2**n|n|g' ./file.sv

> and even used the below way too but getting an error
> sed -i 's|"2**n"|n|g' ./file.sv

> sed: -e expression #1, char 10: Invalid preceding regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Asterisks `*` are a special character in regular expressions. They indicate that the preceding character be matched 0 to many times.

Precede the asterisk with a backslash `\*` to allow the literal asterisk to be matched.

The following will return `n`

```
echo "2**n" | sed 's|2\*\*n|n|g'
```